# How to make a multidimensional array using while loop in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a beginner in c# and I have to write a multidimensional array using while loop. I just can't go through it. So far I have made what I exactly need with nested for loop but can't convert it to while loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int[][] tab = new int[4][];
tab[0] = new int[4];
tab[1] = new int[3];
tab[2] = new int[2];
tab[3] = new int[1];

int num = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < tab[i].Length; j++)
    {
        tab[i][j] = num++;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("tab[{0}] = ", i);
    for(int j = 0; j < tab[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", tab[i][j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(""); 
}
```

Comment: So you're not allowed to use a nested `while` loop? (Is this homework?)

Comment: `int[][]` isn't a multi-dimensional array; it is a *jagged* array - everything there is a "vector" (i.e. one-dimensional)

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes it's part of a homework. I have to write a console app, I have everything ready besides that part with array. It's a warehouse app that makes different operations on stock. I need to put in that array books parameters and print them.

Comment: ...just to add to Marc's comment:  When you do modify it to use a multidimensional array, you will also need to switch to GetUpperBound rather than Length.

Comment: So it is a jagged array and I have to rewrite it using while loop, could be nested i suppose. I just have to use while loop.

Comment: Do you have to use 2 while loops or does one while loop just need to be used?

Comment: @Bad Dub there is no limit to the number of loops

Comment: Also it probably doesnt matter but you dont need the while loop that prints out the results in the console. You can just move the console.writeline comments into the same positions in first while loop.

Comment: @BadDub tried to move comments but something is not working, it stops printing numbers after first jagged array

Comment: I added an answer that seems to work for me locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer to remove redundant console write line loop

```
while (ai < tab.Length)
{
    bj = 0;
    Console.Write("tab[{0}] = ", ai);
    while (bj < tab[ai].Length)
    {
        tab[ai][bj] = num++;
        Console.Write("{0} ", tab[ai][bj]);
        bj++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
    ai++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop is a dressed up `while` loop, you're already very close.

consider that

```
for(a; b; c) { ...; }
```

is equal to (without the break/continue labels for brevity)

```
 { a; while (b) { ...; c; } }
```

You should be able to do this conversion easily. But I think a teacher should also just accept code with a `for` loop as it is functionally a while loop.

Now there could be other constraints in your homework, like allowing nested loops or the  `[,]` or `[][]` style multi dimensional arrays (again, functionally the same, different C# notations for slightly different feature sets).

Comment: Great tip. Really, no one has ever told me that... :)

Comment: Is `for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { continue; }` equal to `int i = 0; while(i < 3) { continue; ++i; }`?

Answer (score 0):

```
           int[][] tab = new int[4][];
            tab[0] = new int[4];
            tab[1] = new int[3];
            tab[2] = new int[2];
            tab[3] = new int[1];

            int num = 1;

            int ai = 0;
            int bj = 0;

            while (ai < tab.Length) {
                bj = 0;
                while (bj < tab[ai].Length) {
                    tab[ai][bj] = num++;
                    bj++;
                }
                ai++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("tab[{0}] = ", i);
                for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", tab[i][j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
```

Just remove **for** loop and added **while** loop.